# Pick property from other type and select from union at same time

Tags: typescript

If i have this type for example:

```js
type Stuff = {
    variants: 'primary' | 'secondary' | 'tertiary'
}
```

And i want a second type with a key of `variants` but with a subset of the union above, lets say for this example only `primary` and `secondary`.

My understanding is you can do it like this:

```js
type StuffThree = {
    variants: Extract<Stuff['variants'], 'primary' | 'secondary'>
}
```

This works, however, i would rather not have to state the key `variants` again, is this possible?.

I have tried the below but it doesn't seem to work

```js
type StuffTwo = Pick<Extract<Stuff, 'variants'>, 'primary'>
```

Here's my attempt in the [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCuAzRUC8UDeAoKuoDcBDAJwEtCA7YAZwC4oByMMgWxJAagB9HqIBjAPYUAJu048GwCMWDliHLAF8sWAPRqoAdUHEA1tQCEUAEbxgUUgxFRihYAAsZUCoIsPC+aMEFQA7mTSUI7QehAgjERklDSchADmhKQUUHwQyfFQhNSW-jHBTqmELKHhWTmEJoJeWKCQsAjIACoOxBDQ6Nh4BCTkVHRQAKIAHsB2-MAAPHBIiADaDFF9sQC6ADSMzKRsChK8AsJiuwB8yqoaUAAigg5QtAAUteDQM81+vugACqT8epMjY0IE2mjUQG0WvRi1AYx3BWx2HGOQA):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a generic type that has this property variants and then use it with different types for the values.

```
type VariantsObject<K> = {
    variants: K
}

type RestrictedVariants = 'primary' | 'secondary'
type AllVariants = RestrictedVariants | 'tertiary';

type Stuff1 = VariantsObject<AllVariants>

type Stuff2 = VariantsObject<RestrictedVariants>
```